# How to move legend after creating plot with mapCountryData

Tags: r, rworldmap

I have created a graph with mapCountryData, but the legend obscures part of the US.  How do I move it?
My plot is created with:

```
t = floor(df$pct/10)*10

malDF <- data.frame(country = df$n,
  m = do.call(paste, c(list(t),'-',list(t+9.99),'%', sep = "")) )

malMap <- joinCountryData2Map(malDF, joinCode = "ISO3",
  nameJoinColumn = "country", verbose = FALSE)

mapCountryData(malMap, nameColumnToPlot="m", catMethod = "categorical",
  missingCountryCol = gray(.8), colourPalette = brewer.pal(5,'RdPu'), mapTitle=paste("Percent ", y[x]), addLegend = T)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a partial fix for this on page 4 of the vignette for the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/vignettes/rworldmapFAQ.pdf). First you set the `addLegend` parameter to `FALSE` in the `mapCounrtyData` call. Then, you can add your own legend with the `addMapLegend` function. This allowes you to use, e.g. a vertical legend instead of a horizontal one. You can also control the width, length and positions relative to the edge of the image.